Wrapping a text about image or another composable
I am just practicing with wrapping a text around an image.
So the text is on the left and when it goes beyond the height of the image it should take the full length of the screen.
I am wondering how to achieve this. Should it be a BoxwithConstraints, a custome Layout. Or can it be done with just composbles rows and columns, box.
Currently my compose looks something like this:
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
    ) {

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
        ) {
            StarRatingBar(movieDetail.voteAverage)

            Text(
                color = Color.Black,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
                text = movieDetail.genres.joinToString(" • ") { genre -> genre.name },
                fontSize = 16.sp,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Start
            )

            Text(
                color = Color.DarkGray,
                text = "Running time ${movieDetail.runtime.minutes}")
            Text(text = "Revenue $${movieDetail.revenue.formatNumberWithSuffix()}")
            /** Don't show if there is zero budget*/
            if (movieDetail.budget > 0) {
                Text(text = "Budget $${movieDetail.budget.formatNumberWithSuffix()}")
            }

            Text(
                color = Color.LightGray,
                fontSize = 22.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                text = "Overview")


            Text(
                color = Color.White,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                fontSize = 18.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
                text = movieDetail.overview
            )
        }

        KamelImage(
            resource = { asyncPainterResource(data = movieDetail.posterPath) },
            contentDescription = movieDetail.title,
            modifier = Modifier.size(150.dp, 250.dp).clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)),
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight,
            onLoading = {_ ->
                CircularProgressIndicator(
                    color = Color.Blue
                )
            },
            onFailure = {
                Image(imageVector = vectorResource(Res.drawable.compose_multiplatform), contentDescription = null)
            },
        )
    }
}

From the image below you can see that the text doens't wrap around it just fills the column width


This question is similar to: How do I wrap text around an image or a composable?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is not easily possible out of the box. Please have a look at the TextFlow library, which already implements that use case.
If you are using Material3, use the following dependency in your build.gradle:
implementation('io.github.oleksandrbalan:textflow-material3:1.2.1')

Then, you can use it as follows:
TextFlow(
    text = movieDetail.overview,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    obstacleAlignment = TextFlowObstacleAlignment.TopEnd,
    obstacleContent = {
        KamelImage(
            resource = { asyncPainterResource(data = movieDetail.posterPath) },
            contentDescription = movieDetail.title,
            modifier = Modifier.size(150.dp, 250.dp).clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)),
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight,
            onLoading = {_ ->
                CircularProgressIndicator(
                    color = Color.Blue
                )
            },
            onFailure = {
                Image(imageVector = vectorResource(Res.drawable.compose_multiplatform), contentDescription = null)
            },
        )
    }
)

The library is using a SubcomposeLayout and a Canvas under the hood to achieve this.
If you want the image to be offset, you can try the offset Modifier on the KamelImage to shift it upwards vertically.
